# Automatically repost WordPress post on LinkedIn Articles

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

A client is asking for an option to automatically repost/copy a published post from WordPress to a LinkedIn article since there's a different audience watching both feeds.

Most created WordPress solutions only facilitate sharing a link to the website post on the standard feed and from what I can find at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/articles-api there seems no option to create articles through an API, only retrieve and delete them.

I was wondering if I missed something or if at the moment it's not possible to create LinkedIn articles through the API. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so because you speak of a client. i will take this as a hint that the article needs posting on the company page.

you should read the following page:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages

this page contains all information regarding managing company pages including adding posts.

> There are two methods for sharing content via the REST API.  The API endpoint is the same, regardless of the method you choose — only the format of the request body differs.
>
> Post a plain text comment.  Note that if the comment includes a
>   fully-qualified URL in it, LinkedIn analyzes the included URL and
>   automatically identifies the title, description, image, etc., to be
>   used as part of the share. Share with specific values — You provide
>   the title, description, image, etc., directly in the body of the
>   request.

**NOTE:**

you cannot use the V2 api's without a partnership with linkedin. the link i provided is for V1 api. this api is for free use. if you necessarily need the V2 then just post a comment and i will explain the proces of the partnership.

Comment: Hello Lars
I would be interested in knowing how to share an HTML post as an article through the Linkedin API. As OP mentions it seems that you are only able to retrieve and delete already created articles. I'm looking for an endpoint to post an article from my website to my company's LinkedIN article. Help would be appreciated. I have signed up for V2 on here https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program